# What is meant by "A still life featuring" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, learning

on the article source by:

https://www.nytimes.com/2022/08/18/t-magazine/hot-chiles-pepper-spice.html

I came across this text under a photograph:

"A still life featuring, from left, orange habanero and poblano chiles, arrayed with Sichuan peppercorns and dark chocolate.  Credit..."

what is meant by: "A still life featuring" The way I interpret this would be something like

what is mentioned after is still a feature in life, Is that it? It might be obvious for native English speakers but not so much for a learning yet mind

Comment: By the way, I don't think you have to include the tags "american-english" and "british-english" unless you are specifically asking a question about those dialects.

Answer (score 5):

A [**still life**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life) is a work of art that depicts a collection of inanimate objects, usually small, common ones.  In this case, the photograph is called a *still life* because the photograph is of an arrangement of chile peppers, chocolate, and Sichuan peppercorns.

[*Featuring*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feature) here means *to include someone or something as an important part*.  (See the verb definition B2 at the link.)

So this is *a picture of small objects, which includes, as its important parts, orange habanero and poblano chiles, arrayed with Sichuan peppercorns and dark chocolate*.

Comment: in this particular case I'm very curious about one thing. could one resuse this phrase: "A still life featuring" in headlinse way in a different context to mean that something is still a feature in life? like in: "A still life featuring, the candle is in current days"??

Comment: No, you cannot use it that way.  The word "still" in "still life" means "not moving", like inanimate objects, not animals or people.  It does not mean "things are still this way."

Comment: So "still life" is one of those "set phrases" right?

Comment: Correct!  It is an idiom.  You can't guess the meaning of the entire phrase from the individual words.

Answer (score 2):

It's a term in painting:

> ***A still life*** (plural: *still lifes*) is ***a work of art depicting mostly inanimate subject matter***, typically commonplace objects which are either natural (food, flowers, dead animals, plants, rocks, shells, etc.) or man-made (drinking glasses, books, vases, jewelry, coins, pipes, etc.).([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life))

So you should understand this sentence as speaking about a work of art ***which is featuring*** all those objects.